# How to add objects in a DIV and appear above the DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image and a textbox inside a DIV that has a opacity of 60%. For some reason the two objects also inherits the opacity as well. How do I prevent it?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="sliderdiv">
<div id="slider">
            <img src="i2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="i3.jpg" alt="Pure Javascript. No jQuery. No flash." />
            <img src="i4.jpg" alt="#htmlcaption" />
            <img src="i5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption" style="display: none;">
            <em>HTML</em> caption. Link to <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>.
        </div>

</div>
<div id="bg">
    <img src="wmlogo.jpg" width="140" height="30" alt="Westmed Medical Group" title="Westmed Medical Group Homepage" id="logoimg" />
    <input type=text size=25 id=insidebgtext />
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: #CC0000;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index: 1;
}
#insidebgtext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 20%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 25;
}
#sliderdiv
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 306px;
z-index:-1;
background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

#logoimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 25;
}
```

How it appears:

[image]

Comment: Did you try giving them a opacity of 0?

Comment: You should apply the opacity with rgba in background color instead of opacity: .6;

Comment: opacity of 0 makes the object disappear and I set it to 1 and it just have the same effect...

Comment: Doesn't work in IE 8 :/ What is the code for IE8?

Comment: rgba doesn't work in IE8 or lower ....

Comment: What is the alternate so it works in IE8 as well?

Comment: use a pseudo-element to fake the opacity background or add another element with absoluteposition and lower zindex value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance of the properties of parents in the child in very obvious. For your purpose you can use a proxy way of **using a transparent png image for the background and avoid the use of opacity** all together.